# How to set default directory for \copypages and \insertpages?

Tags: context, appendix, attachfile

I'm using two macros to insert some PDFs to my document: `\copypages` and `\insertpages`. Is there a **way to specify a default directory** to these macros to search for files?

By info from [ConTeXt wiki for these commands](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/insertpages), I guess this could be achieved with some `\defineexternalfigure` configuration, but I didn't find that.

Reasoning: I use ConTeXt via [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org) to generate PDF, with a custom-made [template](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates) (which is a `.tex` file). When Pandoc generates PDF, it runs ConTeXt in a temporary folder, breaking paths to external PDFs. I already posted this [problem in Pandoc email list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/ZpNjNf5Usu8).

Comment: You can tell ConTeXt to search for images in certain `directories` with `\setupexternalfigures[directory=<PATH>]`. When you set multiple directories you have to enclose the list in curly braces, e.g. `\setupexternalfigures[directory={plants,animals}]`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster thank you! It perfectly works! I'll add an answer linking to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`\setupexternalfigures[directory=<PATH>]`**, which works also to `\copypages` and `\insertpages`.

[Wolfgang Schuster](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/33961/wolfgang-schuster)'s [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544325/how-to-set-default-directory-for-copypages-and-insertpages#comment-1374898) solves the problem. According to [ConTeXt garden wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupexternalfigures) you can specify:

> - `location`: where to find figure files:
>
>   - *global*: search path specified with the 'directory' key
>   - *local*: search in the current directory
>   - *default*: search in the texmf tree
> - `directory`: local directory for figure files
>
> (...) The default setup for the search is `\setupexternalfigures[location={local,global}]`.

So one could use, for instance, `\setupexternalfigures[location={local,global}, directory={/path/to/somewhere]`. ConTeXt would search *first* in current directory, and then in `/path/to/somewhere` for figures and PDFs.